# how to use preg_split() instead of split ()

Tags: php, preg-split

newbee here...

I'm trying to replace the split() functions in a website so I found preg_split() to use. First had to find out how the split() function works so I looked at this example at the php.net site:

```
<?php
// Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen
$date = "04-30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);
echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year<br />\n";
?>
```

The output was as expected:
Month: 04; Day: 30; Year: 1973

So I thought it would be easy and just change it to:

```
<?php
// Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen
$date = "04-30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = preg_split('[/.-]', $date);
echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year<br />\n";
?>
```

Output:
Month: 04-30/1973; Day: ; Year:

What is wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some symbols to define start/end of regular expression. It can be `~`, for example:

```
$date = "04-30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = preg_split('~[/.-]~', $date);
echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year<br />\n";
```

**Update**:

If your code works with `/` as regexp borders, then you have to escape `/` with a backslash:

```
list($month, $day, $year) = preg_split('/[\/.-]/', $date);
```

Comment: Changed it but the output is still the same: Output: Month: 04-30/1973; Day: ; Year:

Comment: Well I got a little further, it has to be a / instead if a ~ like **list($month, $day, $year) = preg_split('/[.-]/', $date);** but now still have to find how to get the / as a split character.

Comment: You found it first ;-) Thank you!